# Quartz scheduler Tirgger job Manually from another webapplication in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

i have two application running in same container lets say WEbApp1 & WEbApp2

1.WEbApp2 is having scheduler job and cron expression defined which run on certain period of time

2.Due to some requirements i wan to invoke WEbApp2 scheduler from WEbApp1 particular execution button to run  scheduler on users demand as well as on cron expression defined time

Comment: You need to look up how to do cross-context calls in your particular Java EE server. This behaviour is not standardised but you can normally configure your container to allow it.

Comment: thanks i was trying the same

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solutions is very simple. Just call WEbApp2 from WEbApp1

For example:

1. WEbApp1 calls https://WEbApp2/jobs/foo
2. WEbApp2 intercepts the request in it's Controller
3. The Controller just calls the Service that the scheduler also calls.

Of course make sure you build in some security so that WEbApp2 also accepts requests from WEbApp1.

Comment: What wud be done if applying load balancer ,in case if the ports and context changes

Comment: A load balancer would not cause problems. The requests stays the same. It is obvious that changing ports and contexts, your asking for problems! That's why you should never hard code stuff but read from a properties files.